# Минералог или минеролог?

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия

Как правильно назвать специалиста в минералогии? Возможны ли варианты в написании, и на какой слог падает ударение в слове *минер(?)лог*...

"Он ге**о**лог или минер(?)лог"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте проведем небольшое изыскание, покопаемся в умных словарях и в современных примерах словоупотребления. Из словаря РЯ 18 века :

> **МИНЕРА** 1718, ы, ж. Ср.-лат. **minera**. Руда. В конференции .. показан разноцвѣтный камень с мѣдною минерою, и ради розыскания отдан доктору Гмелину. МАН I 459.
>
> **МИНЕРАЛО́ГИЯ 1767 (-рол- 1768, -лл- 1802)**, и, ж. **Н.-лат. mineralogia**, непоср. и через. фр. minéralogie. Наука о минералах.
>
> **МИНЕРАЛОГ 1771 (-рол- 1780)**, а, м. Фр. minéralogue, нем. Mineralog. Специалист по минералогии.

[ФЭБ](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/)

Таким образом, термин *минералогия* является новолатинским образованием, составленным из ср.-лат. **minera** (руда) и греческого  **λόγια** (слова). В указанном словаре отмечены формы : *минерология* и *минеролог* (вторая половина 18 в.) В качестве разговорного словарь Ушакова также фиксирует слово :

> МИНЕРОЛОГ, минеролога,
> муж. (разг.). То же, что минералог. Толковый
> словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935 1940

Сетевой поисковик легко находит современных **минерологов** :

> Работа Иркутская обл.. Вакансия Иркутская обл. - Маркшейдер; Геолог; Инженер; **Минеролог.**
>
> Банк вакансий / Рубрика "Хозяйственники"
>
> Вакансия / Хозяйственники 
> МАРКШЕЙДЕР; ГЕОЛОГ; ИНЖЕНЕР; **МИНЕРОЛОГ.**

Можно рассудить, что минерАлог (ударение на последнем слоге) - это большой ученый, крупный специалист и кабинетный в основном работник; минерОлог же (ударение на предпоследнем слоге) - рангом пониже, простой итр, который мотается в геологоразведке. Вот такое разделение получается, если исходить из реалий современного речевого дискурса...

> Дискурс - это **различные виды речевой
> практики**, например, обычный повседневный
> разговор, интервью, лекция, деловые
> переговоры и др.

Answer (score 3):

МинералОг.
Откуда эта сумасшедшая форма "минер**о**лог"? 
В обмен на пат**а**логоанатома?

Comment: Видимо, люди думают, что там соединительная "о" между корнями.

Comment: Ну да, полная форма ведь должна быть *минералолог*, лишнее "ло" убирается. Может показаться, что убирается "ал", хотя это, конечно, нелогично.

Comment: гаплология, о которой у нас тут так много говорили.

Comment: Минера**ло**логия - такое слово существует лишь в воспаленном мозгу фи**ло**логов))) Минералогия - от французского **mineralogie**. Генеалогия - генеалог. Ну, а *минеролог* - разговорная форма, согласно словарю Ушакова : 
> Толковый словарь Ушакова

>МИНЕРОЛОГ
минеролога, м. (разг.). То же, что минералог.

Comment: "Минеролог" звучит как-то ладнее. "Минералог" с ударением на последнее "о" звучит чудно.. есть ли еще такие названия профессий, с ударением на последнее "о" или иную гласную?

Comment: @CopperKettle - *"Минеролог" звучит как-то ладнее* - мне нет. Мне как правильно - так и "ладнее".

Answer (score 2):

Цитата:   Минера**ло**логия - такое слово существует лишь в воспаленном мозгу филологов)))

Скорее, математиков (в моем лице).

Я пробовала поискать этимологию этого слова в интернете, результаты весьма скудные:

**что такое “минералогия”**
*в словаре Современный толковый словарь изд. «Большая Советская Энциклопедия»*

МИНЕРАЛОГИЯ
(от минерал и …логия), наука о минералах, их составе, свойствах, особенностях и закономерностях физического строения (структуры), условиях образования, нахождения и изменения в природе. Возникла в древности, связана с развитием горного дела. Как самостоятельная наука минералогия оформилась в эпоху Возрождения (Г. Агрикола и др.). Термин «минералогия» введен в 1636 итальянским ученым Б. Цезием (Цезиусом). Начало нового этапа развития минералогии связано с именами Р. Ж. Гаюи, А. Вернера, М. В. Ломоносова, В. М. Севергина, Й. Берцелиуса и др. От минералогии отделились кристаллография (18 в.) и петрография (19 в.), в нач. 20 в. - учение о полезных ископаемых, геохимия, кристаллохимия. Основы современной минералогии заложены В. И. Вернадским, У. Брэггом, В. Гольдшмидтом, А. Е. Ферсманом и др. Различают описательную, генетическую, прикладную и ряд др. отраслей минералогии.

Как видите, не только математики возводят происхождение слова к "логии". Кто же прав?

Comment: DocentI, а предмет спора обозначить?
Написание слова "минералогия" и и отсутствие в современном языке слова "минералология" никак не исключают возведение к "логии". 
Абсурдна лишь трактовка его как "минерологии". "Минерология" - это наука о минерах. А не то, что вы подумали.

Comment: >**mineralogy** (n.) 
1680s, a hybrid from mineral (n.) + -logy or else from French minéralogie (1640s). Related: Mineralogist; mineralogical.

>**mineral** (n.)
late 14c., "substance obtained by mining,"
from Medieval Latin minerale "something
mined," noun use of neuter of mineralis
"pertaining to mines," **from minera "mine."**
Meaning "material substance that is neither
animal nor vegetable" is first recorded c.1600.
Modern scientific sense is from 1813. (Online Etymology Dictionary)

"Минеролог" - навроде шахтера, ползает по шурфам, забоям и отвалам, ищет камушки. Найдет в яме и изучает)

Comment: @Behemotus, я не спорю, я спрашиваю. Меня смутил комментарий @Дерзкий про воспаленный мозг. Вот и стало интересно, прав ли он.

Answer (score -1):

Правильное написание - минераллограф! :)

Comment: источник не назовете?